# CodeIgniter create folder with variable name

Tags: php, codeigniter

I've tried a solution from another question ( [codeigniter creating a directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6245965/codeigniter-creating-a-directory) ) where it says to use :

```
$path = "uploads/product";

if(!is_dir($path)) //create the folder if it's not already exists
{
  mkdir($path,0755,TRUE);
}
```

This hasn't worked for me for some reason

This is my code

```
//previous line is me inserting data into the database. $result is the result from the inser.

    if($result)
        {
            if(!is_dir($path))
            {
                mkdir($path,0755,TRUE);

                //print_r("aasifnuoiaasifnuoiaasifnuoiaasifnuoiaasifnuoiaasifnuoiaasifnuoiaasifnuoiaasifnuoiaasifnuoiaasifnuoi");
                redirect('manager/administrator/users/index');
            } 
            else 
            {
                die('Failed to create folders...');
            }

        }
        else
        {
            redirect('manager/administrator/users/index');
        }
```

I have also tried without the variable name but the folder doesn't appear. Please help.

Comment: There isn't one. The folder doesn't appear at all.

Comment: have you enabled `display_errors`?

Comment: May I know where I can add that? Is it at the top of the file?

Comment: Does your server account has rights to create directories under `uploads/products`

Comment: `ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(-1);`

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) _while testing_ right after your opening PHP tag for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` to see if it yields anything.

Comment: Yeah it does. I am using a local server at the moment. And I've placed the code but there are no errors.

Comment: I am able to create a folder manually and upload files onto it. However to create one via this method doesn't work.

Comment: I realized what happened. I put it after redirect thats why I could not generate anything. However I get a header error now. How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm quite sure this is because the directory of $path is not writeable, If that's the case you may need to use the FTP client to give the PHP user permissions to create files and folders on that directory recursively.

```
$path = './assets/files/'.$company;
$announcementpath = $path . '/announcements';
if(!is_dir($path)){
  if(is_writeable('./assets/files/')){
    if(mkdir($path,0755,TRUE)){
      echo "Created $path";
      if(mkdir($announcementpath,0755,TRUE)){
        echo "Created $announcementpath";
      } else {
        echo "Failed to create $announcementpath";
      }
    } else {
      echo "Failed to create $path";
    }

  } else {
    echo 'PHP does not have the privileges to modify "./assets/files/" directory.'
    $stat = stat($path);
    print_r(posix_getpwuid($stat['uid']));

    chmod($path, 0755); // trying to change permissions
    //chown($path, $stat['uid']);
  }

} else {
  echo 'directory already exists.';
}
```

Comment: Currently I am using a local server called MAMP. Is it the same?

Comment: I've tried this but no error appears. It seems like the path is valid but somehow no folder is being created.

Comment: There was a typo in the `if(is_dir($path)){`, try now

Comment: Sorry, nothing echoes out. Could it be because this is done in the controller and not the view?

Comment: Oh I am able to upload files onto a folder that I manually created. Don't know if that is helpful information

Comment: It just confirms it has to do with the permissions the mamp server has over your web root directory tree.

Comment: I've just set the folder permissions to read and write for everyone. Still doesn't work. Sorry. Is there another way to do this?

Comment: @JianYA if you have problems...most likely other MAMP users have had them to and  permissions issue would  turn up in a search

Comment: I realized what happened. I put it after redirect thats why I could not generate anything. However I get a header error now. How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found out what the issues were.
I did not place a name for the directory and that was the cause of the header errors.

```
$path = "./files/".$directory;
        if($result)
        {
            if(!is_dir($path))
            {
                mkdir($path,0755,TRUE);
                redirect('manager/administrator/users/index');
            } 
            else 
            {
                die('Failed to create folders...');
            }

        }
        else
        {
            redirect('manager/administrator/users/index');
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove base url form your path. Your path should be like that

```
$path = "assets/folder/";
```

Comment: Please provide more of an explanation of the rationale behind your answer.